Conditionally render content in Vue parent component based on whether a slotted child component has a prop
In Vue 3, how can a block of code in a parent component template be conditionally rendered depending on whether or not a slotted child component has a prop passed to it?
Take the following code for example:
<Foo>
  <Bar/>
  <Bar baz="baz" />
</Foo>

Conditional slots can be used with $slots in templates, i.e. v-if="$slots.default", but there doesn't seem to be a way to conditionally render certain content in the parent based on whether or not a slot has a prop.
Inside of <Foo/>, note the v-if does not work but this is the idea.
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <template v-if="$slots.default.props.baz">
    <!-- add custom logic here depending on whether or not "baz" prop is present -->
  </template>
  <slot/>
</template>

This also will not work:
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <template v-for="slot in $slots.default">
    <div v-if="slot.props.baz"><!-- do something --></div>
  </template>
  <slot/>
</template>

The only working solution is to use the useSlots() composable and use a render function.
<script setup>
const slots = useSlots()

slots.default().forEach(slot => {
  if (slots.props?.baz)
    console.log('baz prop present')
  else
    console.log('baz prop not present')
})
</script>

The thing is that vue templates are compiled to render functions, so it would seem that there is a way to access props on $slots.

Are you talking about scoped slots? https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots

No, depending on what slots get passed should render a different block in the parent

This is possible with a template. The problem in the original code is that $slots.default is a function which cannot be iterated.
It should be:
<template>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <template v-for="vnode in $slots.default?.()">
    <component :is="vnode" v-if="vnode.props?.baz"></component>
  </template>
</template>

:is="vnode" is a working but undocumented use and can be extended to :is="() => vnode" in case of problems.
Render function is more flexible than a template, and it's more efficient to do this there, as suggested in another answer. And it's even more efficient to do this in script rather than script setup to not work around its limitations:
export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => slots.default?.().filter(vnode => vnode.props?.baz)
  }
}


Interesting, looks like I almost had it. I tried calling $slots.default() without the optional chaining operator and that is probably why it wasn't working and I wrapped $slots.default in pre tags and seen there was a function so I was surprised why calling it wasn‘t working in the template.

That's just common safety measure when you deal with slots, it's to avoid render errors when no children are provided. It's unnecessary here, so there likely was something else why it didn't work

Just wrap your slot logic into a functional component (a render function):
Playground
<script setup>
import {h, useSlots} from 'vue';
const slots = useSlots()

const slotted = () => {
  return slots.default().map(slot => {
    debugger;
    if (slot.props?.baz)
      return h('div', 'A component in the default slot WITH baz prop = ' + slot.props.baz);
    else
      return h('div', 'A component in the default slot WITHOUT baz prop');
  });
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <slotted/>
  </div>
</template>


I‘m aware of this method, but I was more specifically wondering if there was some way to do this in the template since templates are compiled into render functions anyways

@dbzx10299 You write more efficient code with render function, at least in this case. FWIW, it wasn't clear from the question if you know how to use render function with useSlot because it's not straightforward with "script setup"

Manipulating vnodes in a template looks weird, I'd rather make a functional component for such cases so the logic could be used as usual with components/template slots:
Playground
<script setup>
import Slotted from './Slotted'
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <Slotted #="{props, component}">
      <component :is="component" v-if="props.baz">
        Baz: {{ props.baz }}
      </component>
    </Slotted>
  </div>
</template>

For that we create a functional component:
Slotted.js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
export default (_, {slots}) => {
  const self = getCurrentInstance();
  return self.parent.slots.default?.().flatMap(vnode => {
    return slots.default?.({props: vnode.props ?? {}, component: vnode.type});
  });
};

